# Why doesn't setTimeout wait to call a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I want to create a simple game of sorts. I am trying to duplicate a div recursively after a few seconds. After duplicated, it creates the new div with a new unique ID (ID+i).

The idea is that it keeps creating divs and the user has to click on them to remove them for as long as they can before it reaches the max (game over).

It won't properly wait to create the divs. I want to create new divs from the existing one every few seconds, but it either creates all 15 as soon as I run it or it only creates 1 and stops there.

JSFIDDLE -
https://jsfiddle.net/namelesshonor/msrkxq63/

```
function spawnFly() {
if(x >= 15){
    alert("YOU LOST\n15 Flys have infested your screen!");
}
else if(x < 15) {   
    x++; // adds another fly to the counter 
    setTimeout(duplicate(), 2000); // spawns a new fly after a few secs
    animateDiv(); // animate the spawned fly
    spawnFly(); // called recursively until fly count is met
}   
};

function duplicate() {
var original = document.getElementById('fly'+i);
var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
clone.id = "fly" + i++;
clone.onclick = swat;
original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
};

function animateDiv(){
var newq = makeNewPosition();
var oldq = $('.shoo').offset();
var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
$('.shoo').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
  animateDiv();        
});
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `setTimeout` should be the function pointer to `duplicate`, not the result of calling the `duplicate` function.

```
setTimeout(duplicate(), 2000);
```

should be

```
setTimeout(duplicate, 2000);
```

Also, you might be intending to call the `spawnFly` function in the timeout, not the duplicate function.  The duplicate function would then be called immediately to "spawn" a new fly.  Then in 2 seconds, the `spawnFly` function is called to `duplicate` another fly and queue `spawnFly` again.  The way you currently have it set up, the it immediately recurs into the spawnFly function, queuing up 15 flies to spawn in 2 seconds and immediately topping out the fly count (`x`)

Also, you're your increment of `i` causes an off by 1 error such that you're always trying to assign the value of the next fly to `original`.  You should use pre-increment (`++i`) instead of post-increment (`i++`) to get your desired result

All changes applied: 
https://jsfiddle.net/msrkxq63/3/

Comment: Also, not sure if it's intentionally the rules of the game, but if the latest fly (id - 1) is killed, no additional flies are spawned since it's cloning a nonexistent element (element was removed on fly death).  If you want it to continue producing flies, I'd propose you keep your initial fly hidden and use it as a template for future flies.  Or just create your new flies using pure JS.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `setTimeout` in your example, you're passing the result of `duplicate()`, not the function `duplicate` itself as the callback. As duplicate does not return anything, `setTimeout` tries to call the function `undefined`. You could either call it this way (as an anonymous callback):

`setTimeout(function() { duplicate }, 2000)`

or simply,

`setTimeout(duplicate, 2000)`

Comment: It would be great if it could be editted to include cases where the function being timed out has arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice `duplicate()` in `setTimeout(duplicate(),2000);`,
it's a function call.
`setTimeout` 's first parameter is a function.
If you pass `duplicate()`,
it gets evaluated before the wait and looks for the return value and calls that.
Function or not, it waits **after** the function call and ends up doing nothing after
the wait.
So we can say the flow is:
1​. Callback = `duplicate()`(`duplicate` **is called before wait)** = <return value of `duplicate`> instead of the function `duplicate` itself.

2. Milliseconds = `2000`.

3. Call return value after 2 seconds.
The correct code is:
`setTimeout(duplicate,2000)//Note that there are no brackets here`