# 2 AJAX calls not finishing execution before page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The below AJAX calls work (notice the first one calls the second one on success), however on success of the second call it reloads the browser, and the changes are not always displayed immediately without the user having to manually reload the page a second time. Any way to fix this behavior?

```
 self.assign = function () {

        var data = {
            selectedViewsForClient: self.selectedViewsForClient().toString(),
            volPoolIds: populateSelectedVolPoolIds().toString()
        };

        var jsonData = ko.toJSON(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: "../../act/ClientView/assign",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            data: jsonData,
            success: self.removeViews,
            error: handleEditViewsErrors
        });                        
    };

    self.remove = function () {

        var data = {
            selectedViewsForClient: self.selectedViewsAssignedToCandidateForClientUser().toString(),
            volPoolIds: populateSelectedVolPoolIds().toString()
        };

        var jsonData = ko.toJSON(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: "../../act/ClientView/remove",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            data: jsonData,
            success: location.reload(),
            error: handleEditViewsErrors
        });
    };
```

Comment: `success: location.reload()` syntax/logic error. You're initiating the reload before the second ajax request is even sent.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467369/why-doesnt-settimeout-wait-to-call-a-callback

Answer (score 0):

`location.reload()` reloads the page from cache, to force the page to refresh from the server, use `location.reload(true)`, where the `true` forces a server refresh

Answer (score -1):

I added `async: false` to my second call and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Always [be wary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517403/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-using-synchronous-ajax-call) when using synchronous AJAX calls...

Comment: If you can show me a better way to do it I am all ears. I did not see a suggestion.